# Build Quarkus native image with manually linking dependency

Tags: jvm, quarkus, graalvm, graalvm-native-image, quarkus-native

I'm trying to build a native quarkus application (Apple M2 Max chip), however I am using the library [jSerialComm](https://fazecast.github.io/jSerialComm/) for serial communication.

Upon building quarkus via:

```bash
$ /mvn install -Dnative
```

I receive the following error:

```
Detailed message:

        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.constraints.UnsupportedFeatures.report(UnsupportedFeatures.java:126)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.runPointsToAnalysis(NativeImageGenerator.java:810)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: com.oracle.graal.pointsto.constraints.UnresolvedElementException: Discovered unresolved method during parsing: com.fazecast.jSerialComm.android.AndroidPort.getCommPortsNative(). This error is reported at image build time because class com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPort is registered for linking at image build time by command line and command line.
```

Or short:

```
This error is reported at image build time because class com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPort is registered for linking at image build time by command line and command line.
```

Is there a way to fix this error or are *libraries that are registered for linking at image build time by command line or command line* and native builds incompatible?

Answer (score 1):

this is common issue when using libraries not supported by Quarkus. The cause behind it is usually some missing dependency on the classpath.

Please have a look at [this FAQ entry](https://quarkus.io/guides/native-reference#i-get-a-analysiserrorparsingerror-when-building-a-native-executable-due-to-an-unresolvedelementexception-what-can-i-do) of Quarkus' Native Reference Guide for more info.